# Format a string Discord.PY

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a Multi Discord bot. I mostly understand python but cant figure this one out! I am making a welcome command, I can get it to send a message but its custom per server. I save the message to a json file and get the data. I want to make it so the can do {member.mention} etc. How would I format the {} in the string?

```
msg = welcomem[str(member.guild.id)]
channel.send(msg)
```

If I do that it will send: "Welcome {member.mention} to {member.guild.name}! Enjoy you're stay!" I need to format the member.mention and member.guild.name. The JSON looks like this:
`{"1235476747": "Welcome {member.mention} to {member.guild.name}! Enjoy you're stay!"}`

Comment: Check [ask] and provide [mre]. Post all code, errors, etc. as text, not image.

Comment: Also your question can be broken down into "how to read json" and "how to use f-strings", both of which have a wealth of information if you google

Comment: @buran ? that image is from discord. I took a screen shot if it was code I would have put it in a code block.

Comment: I recognize the syntax from JS where you use ${} to access them, but in python I don't think it works the same (Edit: it can, depending on pythonversion). Either concatenate everything or try something like:

"Welcome {} to {}! Enjoy your stay!.".format(member.mention, member.guild.name)

Comment: @DragonInTraining what you said is correct. But this is a custom message. I am taking an argument then putting it into a json. They may have added {member.mention} there self so im trying to turn the that into a format.

Comment: Again, post your code - [mre]. This looks f-string literal and if everything is right it should work (with double quotes because of the apostrophe). However, without any code it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @buran take a look now are you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `await channel.send(eval(f'f"{msg}"'))`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).